# Error: Entity type 'Skill' is not available in this organization

Tags: salesforcedx

"Entity type 'Skill' is not available in this organization". We created a skill for FSL in our scratch org. In sfdx CLI, I tried doing a pull request against this scratch org. There are no conflicts except for this error. Do you have any experience like or similar to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Skill object is available in version 45.0, your scratch org may be on older version. Check your sfdx config file.